# Linq to XML - how do I get this element value

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Fairly simple one, but my knowledge is limited in this area. I'm using the following c# code to access the value of elements within my `SGML and XML documents`.

It's working fine when there is only one element with the given name in the document, but as soon as there are more than one element with the same name it throws an exception, obviously!

I need to use xpath or some other way of specifying the location of the element i'm trying to get the value of.

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(sgmlReader);
 string system = doc.Descendants("chapnum").Single().Value;
 return system;
```

This works fine, if there is only one "`chapnum`" in the doc, but i need to specifically get the value of "`chapnum`" at the following nested location "`dmaddres/chapnum`".

How please?

Here is a sample of the xml doc. I'm trying to get the value of the "`chapnum`" element nested in the "`dmaddress`" element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE dmodule []>
<dmodule xmlns:dc="http://www.purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.s1000d.org/S1000D_2-3-1/xml_schema_flat/descript.xsd">
<idstatus>
<dmaddres>
<dmc><avee><modelic>xx</modelic><sdc>A</sdc><chapnum>29</chapnum>
<section>1</section><subsect>3</subsect><subject>54</subject><discode
>00</discode><discodev>AAA</discodev><incode>042</incode><incodev
>A</incodev><itemloc>D</itemloc></avee></dmc>
<dmtitle><techname>Switch</techname><infoname>Description of function</infoname>
</dmtitle>
<issno inwork="00" issno="001" type="new"/>
<issdate day="20" month="07" year="2012"/>
<language language="sx"/></dmaddres>
<status>
<security class="01"/><datarest><instruct><distrib>-</distrib><expcont
>Obey the national regulations for export control.</expcont></instruct>
<inform><copyright><para><refdm><avee><modelic>xx</modelic><sdc>A</sdc>
<chapnum>29</chapnum><section>1</section><subsect>3</subsect><subject
>54</subject><discode>00</discode><discodev>ZZZ</discodev><incode
>021</incode><incodev>Z</incodev><itemloc>D</itemloc></avee></refdm
></para></copyright><datacond>BREXREF=AJ-A-00-00-00-05ZZZ-022Z-D VERSUB=CDIM-V6</datacond>
</inform></datarest>
<rpc>xxxxx</rpc>
<orig>xxxxx</orig>
<applic>
<type>-</type>
<model model="xxxxx"><mfc>xxxxx</mfc><pnr>xxxxxxx</pnr></model>
</applic>
<brexref><refdm><avee><modelic>xx</modelic><sdc>A</sdc><chapnum>00</chapnum>
<section>0</section><subsect>0</subsect><subject>00</subject><discode
>05</discode><discodev>ZZZ</discodev><incode>022</incode><incodev
>Z</incodev><itemloc>D</itemloc></avee></refdm></brexref>
```

Comment: Your description is much harder to follow than sample XML showing the value you want to find. Please edit your question with an example.

Comment: You should post the sample xml file as well. It will help you got answer more exactly.

Comment: `doc.Descendants("dmaddress").Descendants("chapnum").Single().Value`?

Comment: Thanks Corak. Simple :)

Comment: @Jodrell - Exceptions will be thrown. ^_^; And your answer will be refered to.

Answer (score 2):

like this?

```
string system = doc.Descendants("dmaddres")
    .Single(e => e.Element("chapnum") != null)
    .Element("chapnum").Value;
```

---

```
string system = doc.Root.Element("dmaddres").Element("chapnum").Value;
```

would probably do just as well.